# Install msi package using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to install the Window application driver `msi` package using `cmd /PS`
but couldn't manage that, since seems the package requires user interaction

```
msiexec /i D:\a\test\ultimate\WindowsApplicationDriver_1.2.1.msi /qn
```

Running the command above is not installing the app, and I see no output. I need this app to be installed in the default location, and executed in background.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, Its updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Start-Process`](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html) to installs the msi package from PowerShell using `msiexec` with the `/i` and`/qn` parameters. You can optionally test using the `-wait` parameter of `Start-Process` in case it helps in your particular case. There is also a `/norestart` parameter to use with `msiexec`.

### PowerShell

```
$pkg = "D:\a\test\ultimate\WindowsApplicationDriver_1.2.1.msi";
Start-Process msiexec "/i $pkg /qn";
##Start-Process msiexec "/i $pkg /qn" -Wait;
##Start-Process msiexec "/i $pkg /norestart /qn" -Wait;
```

---

## Supporting Resources

- [Start-Process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)

Comment: awesome seems working now, but since im running this command in a remote instance.

how I can get the installation path after installing using the cmd/PS ?

Comment: Perfect, usually I do that with post install logic using logic in PS such as `If(!(Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe")){<exe does not exist logic>};` but I usually know the explicit path an exe should reside after the app is installed. See if that gives you a starting point, but you are always free to open a different question under different scope if needed and that would be perfectly fine.,

Comment: Sorry it's not working, I did the same steps manually on my local machine to confirm the app successfully installed but unfortunately didn't find the installed package after running the command

Comment: Much appreciated, will wait for your update

Comment: I just tested the install from https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases/download/v1.2.1/WindowsApplicationDriver_1.2.1.msi using all those 3 example ways I posted and when I checked Programs and Files, it appears in there every time. I also see and `test-path` logic works for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe" so unfortunately on the Windows 10 X64 22H2 system I tested it on downloading the MSI manually and installing it with PS terminal locally, it works as expected. I'm not sure what to do to emulate better for your issue?

Comment: Oh okay, hmm seem it's working now only after I open the Powershell terminal as administrator, and yes I can see the package has been installed properly on my local machine.

the question is how I can obtain this privilege as admin to get the same result when I'm running the command remotely, to be more precise I'm using GitHub action with windows instant.

Comment: I see, the way I normally install remotely is with startup script so at startup, the security context is `SYSTEM` so it is already elevated to run as admin. Another method to play with is `invoke-command` using a credential that is administrator. So I tested and this works but file has to be in local path on remote and credential needs to have admin permission `Invoke-Command -ComputerName vmtest0001 -ScriptBlock {
$pkg = "D:\a\test\ultimate\WindowsApplicationDriver_1.2.1.msi";
Start-Process msiexec "/i $pkg /qn";
} -Credential (Get-Credential)` @amrkamel

Comment: awesome thank you for the help :)

Comment: could you check this question might be relevant to this one

https://superuser.com/questions/1755788/bypass-any-user-interaction-when-setting-up-exe-file-using-powershell