# Bypass any user interaction when setting up .exe file using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-11

How to skip or bypass the steps that require user interaction during installation for .exe file

[image]

the following command below launching the installer window then wait for my interaction, I need to bypass this without any user interaction

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Start-Process c:\users\warri\desktop\evernote.exe -ArgumentList "/i /qn /silent /A /norestart" -Wait -PassThru
```

Comment: What is your installer created with? The argument flags depend on what was used to build the install package. Also, https://silentinstallhq.com/evernote-silent-install-how-to-guide/

Comment: Thanks so much, Passing /S /AllUsers
solved the issue

Comment: Please consider adding that as an answer.